# Need to Analyze Tables and Joins

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to create an mobile api for an existing website and the client had told us to implement the api with various list of methods by looking to the existing website and so we need to analyze what are the queries to be framed.

Now my actual question is,

1. Is it possible to check that, what are the sql tables used behind and how are they joined by running different screens of website? (No stored procedures used and all are inline queries)
2. If so how to check that, we have the rights to client's production and db server and apart from that we don't know anything.

As a short i need to check, what are the `TABLES` used and how are they `JOIN`'ed by running every screens of website.

**Update:**

I had tried with `SQL Profiler` and it is returning large number of rows in where it is difficult to trace and after adding `TextData` filter by providing `loginname` i reduced the number of rows.

Now it is returning like this in all rows `exec sp_execute 8581,1,225` and when i run this am getting up this error
`Could not find prepared statement with handle 8581.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the application and use [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to see the query/tables.

Comment: yeah i tried that before and it is really returning large number of rows from where it is difficult to trace and after then i had used filters with it and after that i can see only some rows where it has something like this `exec sp_execute 8581,1,225` and i don't know how to start

Comment: And am not sure whether i had used the filters correctly just given a login name for `TextData` filter